# Can I scale down only the text from a button when the button is active?

Tags: html, css, button, scale

I have cell number to which I gave box shadow and padding, and it looks like a button. Since it is clickable, I changed the settings on the box shadow when the "button" is active so it looks like you're really pressing it.
To do that, when you click/touch, it scales down by a tiny bit, but it scales both the number and the "button".
What I want to do is to scale down only the number when active,but I can't figure out how. I tried to put the number in a span, but doesn't work with :active pseudo (I think because text it is not clickable).
Is there any other way or should I do a button?

I give you both the code and the web page. The code will render horribly so take a look at the webpage, at the cell numbers. (Please **inspect it in mobile mode**. I am bulding it mobile first and there's no media queries yet.)  [Webpage Here](https://adz.netlify.app/contatti.html)

```css
  .cellnumber {
  /* box-shadow */
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px white inset, -2px -2px 10px rgba(30, 30, 30, .5) inset;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.cellnumber:active {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(30, 30, 30, .3) inset, -5px -5px 20px rgba(90, 90, 90, .1) inset;
  transform: scale(.97);
}

.paolo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}


.numeroandiconcell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.cellnumber {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="paolo">
  <div class="numeroandiconcell">
    <a class="cellnumber" href="tel:+393475924197">347 592 4197</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've wrapped the text in a `div` and put the `scale` on that div while keeping the shadow on the `.cellnumber` this works

```css
  .cellnumber {
  /* box-shadow */
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px white inset, -2px -2px 10px rgba(30, 30, 30, .5) inset;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.cellnumber div {
  /* box-shadow */
  transition: all .35s;
}

.cellnumber:active {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(30, 30, 30, .3) inset, -5px -5px 20px rgba(90, 90, 90, .1) inset;
}

.cellnumber:active div {
  transform: scale(.97);
}

.paolo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.iconandname {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.contactname {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.numeroandiconcell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.cellnumber {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.iconasmartphone {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.tap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.chiamaconuntocco {
  font-size: 25px;
```

```html
<div class="paolo">
  <div class="numeroandiconcell">
    <a class="cellnumber" href="tel:+393475924197">
      <div>347 592 4197</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works because unlike span, div is clickable? Or if not, why?

Comment: You're welcome! A `<span>` is an inline elements and Transform property doesn't apply on inline elements. if you changed the display property of the `span` it would have worked aswell

Comment: Got it! Awesome tip, didn't knew it! Really, thanks a lot! :)